# Force two Chart.js doughnut charts with legends to same size in Bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I have two bootstrap columns side by side in which I want to show two related Chart.js doughnut charts. I want to include the legends, so one can easily see the meaning without interactively hovering with the mouse.

The thing is, when Chart.js plots the two doughnut charts, the sizes of the actual charts differ, because the legend in one chart takes up more space comparatively.

What I'd like is to have two doughnut charts side by side, that scale responsively, and where I am certain the actual doughnut is the same size.

Link to jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/emc86oux/1/

```
var chart = new Chart('plot1', {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: [3,6,10,6,1],
          }],
          labels: ["Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet"]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            align: "end",
            position: "bottom"
          },
          responsive: true,
          aspectRatio: 1
        }
      });

var chart = new Chart('plot2', {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            data: [6, 5, 9, 7, 8, 4, 1, 2, 3, 10, 5],
          }],
          labels: ["On", "the", "other", "hand", "we", "denounce", "with", "righteous", "indignation", "and", "dislike"]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            align: "end",
            position: "bottom"
          },
          responsive: true,
          aspectRatio: 1
        }
      });
```

Comment: Better advice from my side is to hide the Legends and do them manually, otherwise is really annoying trying to adjust the canvas sizes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the approach described [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5070), where HTML legends are added in separate div's. I modified the approach for doughnut charts, which set up the chart data slightly differently than bar charts.